# Can't remove image from image field on content type

Tags: 7, media

doing some last minute maintenance on a D7 site. Recently needed to change some of the existing content and am finding that I cannot delete images. In clicking the "Remove" button associated with the field triggers the "doing something" animation with no result. I've modified the image field to no longer required and have flushed the caches. The only thing strange is that I get a 
`Not Found - 404 - Node view blocked` message when viewing the content. No meaningful errors in the watchdog logs.

Update:
The file upload works on my local development machine, but not on the production server. The only error that gets reported is an "invalid X-Frame options"

Comment: D7's EOL is Nov, 2021....

Comment: Yes, but we’re not planning a migration path. Maybe it’s a bad phrasing, but that’s less relevant to the issue. Forgive my poor choice of words

Comment: There is prob a console or log error that you think it's not relevant  but it is.